# Javascript: Replace enter character with "\n" or "<br />"

Tags: javascript, replace

How can I replace the **↵** keys on the soln attribute on the object.. The regex and "\n" doesn't seem to work. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Similar: [How can I replace newlines/line breaks with spaces in javascript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/9849754)